# Yii2 How to make image in Detail view as a hyperlink

Tags: image, hyperlink, yii2

My requirement is that, on clicking the user avatar (profile pic) it should navigate to the user profile page in detail view of Yii2.

Currently, I'm able to display image with the below code:

```
 [
    'attribute'=>'Supplier profile',
     'format' => 'image',
        'value' => function ($model) { 
         return $model->user->filename;

        },                
    ],
```

By changing the above code to HTML like nothing is displayed, (see below code)

```
 [
    'attribute'=>'Supplier profile',
     'format' => 'image',
        'value' => function ($model) { 
        return Html::a(Html::encode($model->user->filename), [ 'view3', 'id' => $model->id] );

        },                
    ],
```

how do i make image as link??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
[
     'label'=>'Image',
     'format'=>'raw',
     'value' => function($model){
          return Html::a(Html::img($model->user->filename, ['alt'=>'yii']), [ 'view3', 'id' => $model->id]);
     }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
return Html::a(Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@img-url'). '/airline.jpg'),['index'])
```

Comment: In my case, I'm not fetching the same image every time, i need to display the one which is stored in DB. so this won't work

Comment: you must use that code in your attribute gridview not just use only